# How to get inner html based on attribute Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the attibute Id.

In console when I type in the following jquery command:

```
$('#LocationRadioButtons a')
```

I get the following output

```
[<a id=​"4" href=​"#">Test​</a>​, <a id=​"5" href=​"#">Test1​</a>​, <a id=​"6" href=​"#">test2​</a>​]
```

Which is an array

If I type in the following jquery command:

```
$('#LocationRadioButtons a').first();
```

It will return the first element in that array:

Test​​

How do I return an element based on it's Id, and return its innerHTML. For example id = 5 innerHTML is test1,

Cheers

Comment: $('#LocationRadioButtons a').find("#5").html()

Comment: Why not use just `$('#5').html()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the html by using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

You can use

```
$('#LocationRadioButtons #5').html();
```

Based off your markup you can actually simply use

```
$('#5').html();
```

PS: I'd refrain from having ids start with a number. [HTML4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) doesn't like this.

Answer (score 1):

while Id is unique for this element you can directly use id to get html

```
$('#5').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#LocationRadioButtons a[id$="5"]').text();
```

Comment: Thanks, instead of hardcoding the id, how do I dynamically set the Id using a variable; $('#LocationRadioButtons a[id="'+currentId+'"]').html() doesnt work

Comment: $('#LocationRadioButtons #' + currentId).html(); ID's are unique, so you dont need to prefix it with the 'a' tag

Answer (score 0):

an id is unique so you can just use the id selector to select an element with a specific id like this:

```
 $('#5').html();
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**
As you already have the elements id, just do

```
$('#5').html();
```

Will alert `Test1`

jquery `each()` loop is useful when you don't have a selector and you want to parse through each element to check for certain condition.

```
$('#LocationRadioButtons a').each(function(index, value){
    var myattr = $(this).attr('id');
    if(myattr=='5') {
        alert( $(this).html() );
    }
});
```